# If a Firewall blocks an incoming Port, and an application listens to that exact port, what happens?

Tags: networking, router, security, firewall, port

Lets assume that I set up a Firewall Rule, that blocks all incoming traffic from Port **23** (*Telnet*).

An Application now tries to listen to Port **23.** .

**What happens?**

Does the Application listen to that port, although the firewall prevents incoming Traffic an the Application does just not recieve any data from that port?

Or does the Firewall also **prevent the Application from actively listening to that port?**

Comment: The magic answer is: it depends. Are we talking about a software firewall on the same machine? Or on another machine? Or a hardware firewall/firewall appliance?

Comment: Also, note that using *hosts*, rather than a true firewall rule, may be *ignored* by an application. For example Windows ignores *hosts* for some items: https://petri.com/windows-10-ignoring-hosts-file-specific-name-resolution/

Comment: The firewall does not block programs from listening to messages that will never come.

Comment: generally speaking, the port will be created and accessible to any interface it is bound to that is NOT restricted by the firewall. the application will not know anything about the firewall rule, unless it has been specifically programmed do do some kind of check to reveal that fact.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the firewall and how it is configured.

If we talk about a traditional firewall, such as Windows Firewall, then when the firewall blocks the port, you specify the interface it blocks for. The firewall is then a layer between incoming signals and the software, but the software can still open a port and function.

If the firewall doesn't block everything, then the software may even get a connection from local host.

But even if the firewall blocks as much as it can, the same applies.

If the firewall is not on the same computer, but say, a network router, then the same applies still, the firewall blocks everything that goes between it as per how the rules are configured.

Then there are also software firewalls. Aka, firewalls that don't just block ports, but block the creation of a listening socket. In this case, such firewall can prevent software from even creating a socket, which may crash the software in case it was coded poorly.

Although both are legitimate ways, I'm fairly sure you are talking about the classic firewall, and that gives the answer: the port exists, but communication can't reach it.